# openlayers crossOrigin parameter makes the layer dissappear

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

This is realy a stange behavior I have ever seen with openlayers.

I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/minxie/kpL5fuhx/) to demonstrate the issue.

**The strange behavior is**: as soon as I add the parameter `crossOrigin` to my layer, the layer just disappears, you can try it in the jsfiddle (You need to enable the `crossOrigin` parameter again). Or see it below:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [

  ],
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    maxZoom: 25,
    center: [8.86, 54.13],
    zoom: 10,
  })
});

var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
    preload: Infinity,
  url: 'http://service.gdi-sh.de/WMS_SH_BDDcol_KF?',
  params: {
    'LAYERS': 'DTK5col,DTK25col,DTK50col,DTK100col,UEK250,UEK600,UEK1500',
    'TILED': true,
    'STYLES': new String(''),
    'FORMAT': 'image/jpeg',
    'SRS': 'EPSG:4326',
    'VERSION': '1.1.1'
  },
  serverType: 'geoserver',
  //crossOrigin: 'anonymous' //<-- as soon as I enable this line, the layer dissappers
});

var wmsLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: wmsSource
})

map.addLayer(wmsLayer);
```

**I need the `crossOrigin` parameter to avoid another problem with `forEachLayerAtPixel()`:**

> https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/269937/openlayers-4-method-foreachlayeratpixel-throws-securityerror-the-operation-is

**The solution is simply to add the `crossOrigin` parameter to all my layers and which works fine for all the other layers I have**, but only for this layer, it makes the layer dissappear.

More interesting: If I open the debbug on firefox and see the request made to the server. It has status 200 and all the imgs are successfully loaded (you can even see the img in the network analyse)

**So I am wondering, if the layer can be loaded and the pics are there, what makes the layer disappear?** As soon as I cancel the line with `crossOrigin`, all the things go normal.

Answer (score 4):

That happens when the WMS server isn't CORS enabled, or if you try to access an http server url from an https application.  You can still load it without the crossOrigin parameter but the image will be tainted.  First try changing the WMS url from http to https, but if that doesn't work you will need to use a same origin (or CORS enabled) proxy.  To ensure the WMS parameters are passed correctly you will need to URI encode the tile url when loading it, for example:

```
var wmsSource = new ol.source.TileWMS({
    preload: Infinity,
  url: 'http://service.gdi-sh.de/WMS_SH_BDDcol_KF?',
  params: {
    'LAYERS': 'DTK5col,DTK25col,DTK50col,DTK100col,UEK250,UEK600,UEK1500',
    'TILED': true,
    'STYLES': new String(''),
    'FORMAT': 'image/jpeg',
    'SRS': 'EPSG:4326',
    'VERSION': '1.1.1'
  },
  serverType: 'geoserver',
  crossOrigin: 'anonymous',
  tileLoadFunction: function(imageTile, src) {
    imageTile.getImage().src = 'myproxy.php?url=' + encodeURIComponent(src);
  }
});
```

I've now checked the WMS service you are using - it is not CORS enabled in either http or https, so you will definitely need to use a proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer first. But sadly I am not so familier with the `titleLoadFunction()` you wrote in your example. Can you maybe explain a little bit more to me?

Comment: It lets you override the url that OpenLayers uses to load the image object it uses for a tile.  The default action is `imageTile.getImage().src = src`;  where `= src` is the normal tile url.  But if you are using a proxy you will need to change that to the proxy url with the normal tile url as the proxy's parameter.  Setting an image source url in javascript is described here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_img_src.asp

Answer (score 1):

The problem has happened because the server (in your case, jetty) has not been CORS enabled. So you should change the configurations of the server. Do these two steps:

- Download [this file](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-servlets/9.2.13.v20150730/jetty-servlets-9.2.13.v20150730.jar) and put it in `webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\lib` directory under the installation folder of Geoserver (You should use the file compatible with your jetty, so you may find another library appropriate [from here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlets)).
- Go to `webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF` and open `web.xml` file. Uncomment these two tags.

this:

```
  <filter>
      <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
```

and this

```
  <filter-mapping>
      <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Now stop and start Geoserver again to verify if the issue is now resolved.

Comment: Changing the server settings is not an option when you are using a public source such as the Schleswig-Holstein regional government geoportal.

Comment: Then you should contact them to do so. If you want to use a service published on someone else's server, they must first allow you by enabling CORS on their server, so you can access the service from other domains.